# How to calculate current page number and the last page number in birt

Tags: report, master-pages, footer, birt, page-numbering

Is there a way to calculate the current page number and the last page number as expression in Birt? I need the last page number but without using the auto text variables in the "master page" part. I need this for the visibility part of the "layout part" in birt.

Comment: Have you got any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the expression from Master page and paste it in the Layout page. It worked for me!
From Master Page:

[image]

Page number shown after printing the report in PageLayout:

[image]